# Given the generators of a group find the parametrization matrix

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have the generators of $sl(2,\mathbb{R})$ algebra

$$J_0=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ -1&0\end{pmatrix},\quad J_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&-1\end{pmatrix},\quad J_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

They satisfy the commutation relations

$$[J_0,J_1]=-2J_2,\quad [J_0,J_2]=2J_1,\quad [J_1,J_2]=2J_0$$

Now, I need to find the matrix $M(a,b,c)$ such that I can linearize it and get the $J_i$ generators such that it is valid

$$J_i=\frac{\partial M}{\partial k}\Bigg|_{(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)}$$

where $k=a,b,c$ respectively for $i=0,1,2$. Plus matrix M has to be element of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, so $det(M)=1$ for all $a, b, c$.

I've tried manually, and I can find M, but usually I cannot get that $det(M)=1$.

Is there some kind of procedure step by step to do so? Some kind of system of equations or?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Lie algebra basis $e_1, ..., e_n$, then the function $f=exp(e_1t_1)\cdot ...\cdot exp(e_nt_n)$ will satisfy $\frac{df}{dt_i}(0,...,0)=e_i$.

Or in general you can first construct one-variable functions $F_i(t)$ such that $F_i(0)=e$ and $F_i'(0)=e_i$. Then the product $F_1(t_1) \times ... \times F_n(t_n)$ will satisfy the desired relations.

In your case $$F_0(a)=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1-a^2 & a  \\
-a & 1  \\
 \end{array} \right), F_1(b)=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
e^{b} & 0  \\
0 & e^{-b}  \\
 \end{array} \right), F_2(c)=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1+c^2 & c  \\
c & 1  \\
 \end{array} \right)$$

Comment: Is this unique solution or are there others? How did you find those  that fit the $F_i(0)=e$ and $F_i'(0)=e_i$?

Comment: No, there are many solutions (for example, there are a lot of ways to choose $F_i$). You can construct $F_i$'s by taking matrix exponent.

Comment: Ok, so my matrix M should just be the product of these three? Because I don't get that the M has determinant 1 :\

Comment: Yes, it should. Each matrix has the determinant one, so the product also has determinant one

Comment: But when I make a product I get $1-2c^2$ for determinant :\ Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: well, yes. What's your resulting matrix?

Comment: $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a e^{-b} c+\left(1-a^2\right) \left(1-c^2\right) e^b & e^{-b} a+\left(1-a^2\right) c e^b \\
 c e^{-b}-a \left(1-c^2\right) e^b & e^{-b}-a c e^b \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: $1+c^2$ everywhere...

Comment: Is it just normal matrix multiplication or?

Comment: It is normal matrix multiplication. But look at the formula for the third matrix. Where did you get $1-c^2$?

Comment: Oh! My mistake! Sorry :D Now it's good :) Thanks for the help :)